# Multilevel Modeling in stata

Tags: generalized-linear-model, modeling, structural-equation-modeling

I would like to make a model that calculates the probability of disease.
Range of variables are following:
disease ~ (0, 1); score ~ (1-10); test ~ (0-30)
Large values of test and score indicates that there is disease.

```
id   disease    score   test index_score  index_test
1    0           2       10      1            1
1    0           2       20      1            2
1    0           6       10      2            1
1    0           6       20      2            2 
2    1           9       27      1            1
2    1           9       29      1            2
3    0           3       12      1            1
3    0           4       10      2            2
3    0           3       10      3            2
3    0           2       10      4            2
```

Index variables indicate that how many times test or score is measured.
I am trying to model this use the logit model with disease as response and predictors (score, test).

I want to get updated probability of disease with respect to test and scores. What would be best model for this unbalanced data (because score frequently measured)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could fit a mixed effects logistic regression. In Stata you can use `xtmelogit`. For  a random intercepts model you could use the following syntax:

```
xtmelogit disease c.score c.test || id: , or
```

which will treat `score` and `test` as continuous variables and report fixed effects as odds ratios

Comment: Thanks for your help! If doctors update test or score measurement, then I want to predict the probability of disease. Will this model serve this purpose? Shouldn't I use indices of score and test in the model?

Comment: @statuser This model includes score and test so I don't know what you mean "Shouldn't I use indices of score and test in the model?". If you want to include a random slope for (for example) `score` then use `|| id:score` . As for predictions, yes, you can use the model, you just need to take care with how you deal with the random effects in the predictions.